# How to fix the links clipped by an unconnected area in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, clip

I'm trying to clip my target shapefile with a given example area.

The given example area looks like the following pic:
[image: example area]

And there is a river separating two areas. However there are links connecting two area such as bridges on my target shapefile. After I use the geography tool-clipping on my target shapefile, those bridge links are deleted.

Is there a way for me to add those bridge links back to the result shapefile?

Comment: Try using a **Merge** or **Union** tool.